# SQL Server Query in bacth file

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I want to create a batch file to execute a SQL server Query :

QUERY :

```
SELECT CAST(userid AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, checktime, 103) + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), checktime, 8)
FROM checkinout;
```

The query already running ok when i execute in SQL management studio 2005. but after i create batch file, the query is not working & not create .txt file in the location

BATCHFILE:

```
sqlcmd -S DSK-FAC-07\SQLEXPRESS -d AttandaceDB -E -Q "SELECT CAST(userid AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, checktime, 103) + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), checktime, 8) FROM checkinout;" -s "," -o "C:\Report\kiireport.txt"
```

The goal is when the batch file executed, its will create txt file thats contains query data

Thank you

Comment: **Always** declare your length, scales and precisions when using datatypes. You will end up with unexpected behaviour (truncation) if you don't.

Comment: *"when i execute in SQL management studio 2005"* SSMS 2005? What version of SQL Server are you using? SQL Server 2005 has been completely unsupported for about 5 years; it's long past time to look at upgrade paths.

Comment: "_the query is not working_" is vague: was there no response whatsoever? any error messages?. Please [edit] the question to show the _exact_ output you got. You might also try it without the `-o filename` and – at least initially – with a simpler query.